# Conditional GROUP BY clause in Hive QL

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera, hiveql

i'm trying to parameterize the GROUP BY clause in a Hive QL script.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS sales, country, state, city
FROM    testdb.data
WHERE
    PRICE > 5

GROUP BY
    IF (TRUE,
       (country, state, city),
       (country, state)
    )
```

How could such a query be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using CASE statement in GROUP BY and its works. 
You might want to verify the result of query though.
If you can morph your condition into case statement this query can work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM testdb.data
WHERE price > 5
GROUP BY country, state
 CASE <cond>
  WHEN <val> THEN city
 END ;
```